# how can i sort this output?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I created an output for incorrect and correct classification. I want to sort the output for correct classifications by prediction_prob. This is my code so far:

```
for input, prediction_prob, prediction, label in zip(test_text, test_pred_prob, test_pred_class, test_label):
  if prediction == label:
    print(input, '\n\n', prediction_prob, '\n\n', 'has been machine coded as', prediction, 'and should be', label, 'according to human coding.' '\n\n-----\n')
```

This is an example of my output:

```
mailtext1

 tf.Tensor([0.7113831  0.28861693], shape=(2,), dtype=float32) 

 has been machine coded as 0 and should be 0 according to human coding.

-----

mailtext2

 tf.Tensor([0.02235095 0.97764903], shape=(2,), dtype=float32) 

 has been machine coded as 1 and should be 1 according to human coding.
```

This is my first question, and I am relatively new to python. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: The question is not clear to me. Can you provide a sample of your desired output?

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is my desired output:

`mailtext

 tf.Tensor([0.99  0.01], shape=(2,), dtype=float32) 

 has been machine coded as 0 and should be 0 according to human coding.

-----

mailtext

 tf.Tensor([0.98  0.02], shape=(2,), dtype=float32) 

 has been machine coded as 0 and should be 0 according to human coding.

-----

mailtext

 tf.Tensor([0.97  0.03], shape=(2,), dtype=float32) 

 has been machine coded as 0 and should be 0 according to human coding.

-----
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that uou want to sort `zip(test_text, test_pred_prob, test_pred_class, test_label)` by the second value in the second  argument (`test_pred_prob`) in the descending order

You can do this like so. First we stub some data

```
test_text = ['mailtext1', 'mailtext2']
test_pred_prob = [tf.constant(np.array([0.7113831,  0.28861693])), tf.constant(np.array([0.02235095, 0.97764903]))]
test_pred_class = [0,1] 
test_label = [0,1]
```

Next we zip and sort it

```
all_test_data = zip(test_text, test_pred_prob, test_pred_class, test_label)
all_test_data_sorted = sorted(all_test_data, reverse = True, key = lambda t: t[1][1])
```

The sorting function is `sorted()` and of note is the `key` argument that picks your correct classification probability. `reverse=True` as we want a descending order

We can check this list now to see if we got it in the right order:

```
all_test_data_sorted
```

produces

```
[('mailtext2',
  <tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=float64, numpy=array([0.02235095, 0.97764903])>,
  1,
  1),
 ('mailtext1',
  <tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=float64, numpy=array([0.7113831 , 0.28861693])>,
  0,
  0)]
```

as expected. Now you can do your print loop suitably modified to loop over the sorted tuples:

```
for input, prediction_prob, prediction, label in all_test_data_sorted:
  if prediction == label:
    print(input, '\n\n', prediction_prob, '\n\n', 'has been machine coded as', prediction, 'and should be', label, 'according to human coding.' '\n\n-----\n')
```

if you want to sort by the **first** value in your tensor you would use `key = lambda t: t[1][0]` in the `sorted()` function